# If I have two versions of python3 installed on my machine (ie: 3.11.2 and 3.12), how do I set the default version to use when running python scripts?

Tags: apt, python3, source, version

I installed the earlier version (3.11.2) normally using **apt** package manager and the later version (3.12) manually from source.  When I execute python scripts like so:

```
./python_script.py
```

The script uses the earlier version instead of the later one.  I would like to leave the default shebang line `#!/usr/bin/env python3` at the beginning of the script alone for portability reasons.

Here is a sample test script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

def main():
  print(sys.version)

main()
```

[image]

EDIT: With the above configuration, I'm thinking at this point the quickest fix (probably not the best because of future consequences, please see well explained answers and comments from the community below) is to change the target of the python3 symlink in **/etc/alternatives** to **/usr/local/bin/python3.12** where my python3.12 binary is stored.

[image]

EDIT2: As seen in the second screenshot, I was able to get `./myscript.py` to use the python version I wanted (3.12) by verifying that the `/usr/local/bin` directory is before the `/usr/bin` directory in my `PATH` environment variable and renaming the `python3.12` binary in `/usr/local/bin/` to `python3`.

Comment: I use `pyenv` (https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) for this. It makes it very easy to install and select different versions of python.

Comment: I highly recommend pyenv

Comment: It’s nice to see good answers being essentially ignored :-/. I’ve updated my answer to try to explain why your quickest fix is a really bad idea.

Comment: Well, I put `/usr/local/bin` containing my own `python3.12` built binary before `/usr/bin` the system default in the `PATH` (See picture above).  As you can see, when I run ./myscript.py the interpreter still uses the `3.11.2` system version of python.  I must be missing something :-/ ?

Comment: Figured it out, had to rename `python3.12` to `python3` in the `/usr/local/bin` directory (See second screenshot added above)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you’re using `env python3`, the default version of Python will be determined by whichever version of `python3` is first in the `PATH` variable. You can thus choose which version is used by constructing your `PATH` variable appropriately: if you want the system default, ensure `/usr/bin` appears before any other directory containing `python3`, and if you want your own build of Python, ensure the directory containing that version of `python3` appears before `/usr/bin`.

Your proposed solution is one of the worst you could apply at this point. Given the situation shown in your screenshot, you haven’t broken your system yet: system Python scripts, which specify `#!/usr/bin/python3` in their shebang, can still find the modules they expect. If you change `/usr/bin/python3` to point to Python 3.12, those scripts will lose access to the 3.11 modules installed on your system; in particular, `python3-apt`. This is liable to have unfortunate consequences.

Since you are specifying `#!/usr/bin/env python3` in your own scripts, and can therefore rely on `PATH`, I still think a `PATH`-based approach is better in your circumstances. You can even change `PATH` everywhere, to point to your `python3` first, without breaking system Python scripts (since they *don’t* rely on `PATH` to find Python).

Comment: Stephen, I added another screenshot and edit above which shows that I was able to use my own build of python by using the PATH-based approach that you suggested.  Running, ./myscript.py uses the 3.12 intepreter instead of the 3.11.2 one.  If I missed anything or did something incorrectly or shouldn't have let me know.

Answer (score 10):

To complement [@StephenKitt's fine answer](/a/760618), on Debian-based systems, you may be able to install packages for more than one version of python concurrently. For instance here on Ubuntu 22.04, I have 3.10 and 3.11 installed:

```
$ aptitude search -F%p '~i ~n "^python[0-9.]*$"'
python3
python3.10
python3.11
```

The `python3` package depends on `python3.10` and the `python3` executable is a symlink to `python3.10`.

```
$ zstat +link --  ${(v)commands[(I)python[0-9.]#]}
/usr/bin/python3 python3.10
/usr/bin/python3.10
/usr/bin/python3.11
```

**Do not** change that symlink manually. `python` versions are often incompatible between each other, and python modules are not shared between python versions, so changing that python3 symlink will break the scripts that have a `#! /usr/bin/env python3` or `#! /usr/bin/python3` (or `#! /bin/python3` as `/bin` is often a symlink to `/usr/bin` nowadays) and expect python3 to be 3.10 and have access to the python modules installed for 3.10.

So if you need to invoke a script that needs a different installed version of python, and you can't change the shebang to `#! /usr/bin/python3.12`, either just invoke it as:

```
python3.12 /path/to/that-file.py
```

Or create a:

```
mkdir ~/.python3-is-python3.12
ln -s /usr/bin/python3.12 ~/.python3-is-python3.12/python3
```

And put `~/.python3-is-python3.12` ahead in your `$PATH` **but only for the invocation of that script**, setting it globally would likely break other scripts that use `#! /usr/bin/env python3` and expect `python3` to be the system's default `python3`.

Comment: For what it's worth, the strategy of injecting directories into your `$PATH` as described in this answer is more or less what [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) does in a more user-friendly way.

Answer (score 10):

I know this questions only asks about the `apt` package manager, and the other answers cover that aspect very well.

But if you are working with several different python projects, all requiring different python versions and/or different dependencies, I would strongly recommend using a virtual environment (`venv`) to manage the python versions and the dependencies of your projects.

To install a virtual environment for a project, e.g. for 3.11, In the project's main directory, run:

```bash
python3.11 -m venv venv
```

This will create a directory named `venv` containing the virtual environment.

Then, to use the environment, type:

```bash
. venv/bin/activate
```

From that point on, in the current shell you will be able to run `python` and `pip` without the version number, and the correct environment will be used. To get out of the environment, type `deactivate`.

In the new environment you will have only the `pip` dependencies that you installed inside it, so you won't have any dependency mismatches between projects. You will also be able to easily create the `requirements.txt` file for the project with `pip freeze > requirements.txt` after you have installed the dependencies.

Answer (score -2):

Since you're using Debian (or one of its derivatives), you could consider using the `update-alternatives` utility.

For example to set the default to your 3.12 version residing in (for example) /usr/local/bin/:

```bash
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/local/bin/python3.12 10
```

The response should be something like this (I've not actually installed Python 3.12):

```
update-alternatives: using /usr/local/bin/python3.12 to provide /usr/bin/python3 (python3) in auto mode
```

See `man update-alternatives` for details, and other options.

Comment: **No**, `update-alternatives` isn’t made for this. I know it’s an extremely popular idea, but Python packages in Debian and derivatives do *not* use `update-alternatives` and setting this up is a common way of breaking the system (especially in Ubuntu or derivatives where some essential tools rely on Python).

Comment: For our discussion, the key part in the man page is this: “When each package providing a file with a particular functionality is installed, changed or removed, `update-alternatives` is called to update information about that file in the alternatives system.” The alternatives system is set up by packages which participate in it; the system administrator’s involvement is supposed to stop at choosing between available alternatives. Attempting to use alternatives with packages which don’t use the alternatives system is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: I said that the administrator’s role stops at choosing between alternatives. In automatic mode, the system chooses on its own; in manual mode, the administrator chooses (more precisely, if the administrator chooses, the system switches to automatic mode).

Comment: Leaving aside whether one version of Python can replace another, using `update-alternatives` for `python3` involves replacing a packaged file (`/usr/bin/python3`), which is a bad idea in general. Look at the output of `dpkg -S /usr/bin/vi /usr/bin/python3`: the former is an actual alternative, and isn’t owned by any package; the latter isn’t an alternative, it’s owned by `python3-minimal`. The first rule for users of packaged distributions is that you don’t touch packaged files in `/usr`.

Comment: As far as Python 3.11 and 3.12 being alternatives is concerned, they aren’t: there are breaking changes between 3.11 and 3.12, and system-installed Python 3.11 modules aren’t automatically made available on 3.12. Thus a package expecting `/usr/bin/python3` to be Python 3.11 is liable to break if it’s another version of Python. The Python tools in Debian allow packages to be built for multiple Python versions, but that’s decided when the package is built, it can’t be added by the administrator after the fact (except by rebuilding).

Comment: @Seamus Python 3.11 and Python 3.12 are not alternatives. They are _NOT_ 100% compatible with each other (easy example, Python 3.12 dropped four modules from the standard library that were present in Python 3.11, and PEP 701 being implemented in 3.12 means that you can do things in 3.12 with f-strings that you can’t in 3.11). And, on top of that, system-wide site-packages (third party modules) are installed per-version on Debian systems, so the system-wide modules may not be the same between the two versions.

Comment: I wrote “more precisely, if the administrator chooses, the system switches to automatic mode” above — that’s not what I meant. When the administrator explicitly chooses an alternative, the system switches to *manual* mode (ensuring that, as far as possible, the administrator’s choice is preserved when packages are upgraded, installed etc.).

Comment: Re: your introductory paragraph, note that if you know your answer as it stands is currently not good and you plan to fix it later, what you can do is delete it and come back later to edit it and then undelete it. That also avoids attracting downvotes.

Comment: Seamus - instead of defacing your answer with that big heading, you should _delete_ your answer, edit it while it's deleted, then _undelete_ it when it's correct.

Comment: @Seamus, you won't lose reputation while it's deleted, as that prevents people voting on it (that's part of the point of deleting your answer while you correct it).

Comment: @TobySpeight I think Seamus is referring to the overall rep situation on this post: two upvotes, three downvotes, so +14 overall. Deleting the answer drops 14 points from Seamus’ reputation. As you say however deleting it prevents further reputation loss from downvotes (or gains from upvotes).

Comment: @Stephen, doesn't undeleting reinstate the rep?  I'd always assumed that it would.

Comment: @TobySpeight yes, it does, perhaps Seamus wasn’t aware of that.